Can we use past perfect to emphasize completiton?

I did it by Monday

I'd like to ask you if we can rewrite this sentence using past perfect just to emphasize the completiton.

I had done it by Monday

Does 2 mean the same as 1? 2 is better at showing or emphasizing the completition?
Btw. I saw some similar questions but I didn't like the answers they didn't satisfy me. So, I'd like to kindly ask you to answer my question.

No. The defining feature of Past Perfect isn't about "completion" (which often applies to Present Perfect, but that's not what you're asking about). You use Past Perfect when the preceding conversation / narrative is already focused on some time in the past, and you want to refer to something that happened before that "narrative reference time". And if you're not sure that applies, just don't use Past Perfect.

Does this answer your question? Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?

Related: Past and future perfect

I keep telling you to install a spellchecker. For example, in the title, the second sentence and fourth it's COMPLETION.

I'm closing this question because the example sentences aren't idiomatic English and are arguably not grammatical, so they cannot be meaningfully compared.

It's also eerily similar to this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/353106/past-and-future-perfect

Perfect tenses (past perfect, present perfect, and future perfect) are used to emphasize the completion of an action relative to another point in time. This distinction is similar across past, present, and future tenses, each serving to highlight when an action is completed and its relevance to another event or time frame.
Past Tenses:

Simple Past: "I did it by Monday."
This sentence states that the action was completed by Monday but does not emphasize the timing as strongly.

Past Perfect: "I had done it by Monday."
This emphasizes that the action was definitely completed before Monday. It highlights the timing and ensures clarity about the action's completion relative to Monday.


============================
Present Tenses:

Present Simple: "I do it."
Used for habitual actions, general truths, or actions happening now in an informal context.

Present Perfect: "I have done it."
This emphasizes that the action has been completed at some unspecified time before now, often with relevance to the present moment. It highlights the result or completion of the action.


============================
Future Tenses:

Future Simple: "I will do it by Sunday."
This indicates that the action will be completed at some point before or on Saturday but does not strongly emphasize the completion.

Future Perfect: "I will have done it by Sunday."
This emphasizes that the action will definitely be completed before Saturday. It clearly indicates that by the time Saturday arrives, the action will already be finished.


Past Perfect Tense: How to Use It, With Examples
What is the perfect, and how should I use it?

I wouldn't exactly say that it emphasises completeness, but there is a slight difference in inference:
"I did it by Monday" suggests that Monday was the deadline for completion of the task and that you met that deadline.
"I had done it by Monday" means that, by Monday, you had finished it.

Would you say it works similar to futre simple and future perfect. 1 I will do it by Saturday 2 I will have done it by Saturday.?

This answer didn't deserve its downvote. Yes, the perfect expresses  completion. It's not necessarily a deadline but "deadline" is a reasonable practical scenario to use as an example.

Thank you TimR for thid answer
